# [14.10]Change vino port

Tags: 14.10, vnc, vino

I opend gconf-editor(as seen on another post) but when entering Desktop -> Gnome, it seems nothing related to "remote access" is there.

Thanks in advance! :)

(couldn't add a picture, sorry.)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `dconf-editor` instead `gconf-editor`.

The settings for vino are there in `org` -> `gnome`-> `desktop` -> `remote-access`.